# TensorFlow Object Detection API not fine-tuning TensorFlow 1 models correctly?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am trying to train a model by fine-tuning from a pre-trained tf1 model from tf1_detection_zoo (found here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md). However, when I start the training process and initiate evaluation with the newly generated training checkpoints, the model makes zero detections. I printed out the weights of the model and it appears that they are default values and not fine-tuned from the pre-trained model.

I started the training process using the following script to generate the new checkpoints.

```
python model_main.py
--model_dir={path to model directory}
--pipeline_config_path={path to config}/pipeline.config
```

Then, I started the evaluation process with the same script but with different parameters.

```
python model_main.py
--model_dir={path to model directory}
--pipeline_config_path={path to config}/pipeline.config
--checkpoint_dir={path to model directory that contains newly created model.ckpt files}
```

When evaluating, the model makes zero detections and has 0% accuracy even though it is supposed to be fine-tuned from a pre-trained model. Also, when I printed the variables in the estimators, I got different values for the weights.

I've verified that the model isn't making zero detections because of the dataset I'm using, and I have tried multiple different configurations for fine-tuning in the pipeline.config file.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is unclear what your specific question is or what the objective of this post is. Please see how [to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Most of the times when these errors occur is when the model_dir is not set to the correct folder, it has to be set to a new folder that is independent from the pretrained model you want to use. The path to the pretrained weights is linked inside the pipeline config path.